# If you change an environment variable in another shell will it change or stay the same in other shells?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, tcsh

If I create a environment variable in bash such as SPORT=baseball, then switch to tcsh and change it to "running". If I change back to bash will SPORT be displayed as "running"?
(I would try it myself but I only have bash)

Comment: did you try it? what did you find?

Comment: @tink I only have bash. I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a practical experiment that does exactly what you asked about; it runs `bash`, sets an environment variable, then starts `tcsh` and changes its value. Then it checks the value in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export SPORT=baseball
printf 'SPORT is "%s"\n' "$SPORT"

tcsh -c 'echo $SPORT; setenv SPORT archery; echo $SPORT'

printf 'SPORT is "%s"\n' "$SPORT"
```

Running this `bash` script, which invokes `tcsh` will result in

```
SPORT is "baseball"
baseball
archery
SPORT is "baseball"
```

But we don't even have to switch to `tcsh` to see this in action, it's enough to introduce a subshell, which has a separate environment, with `(...)` in our `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SPORT=baseball
printf 'SPORT is "%s"\n' "$SPORT"

(
    echo "$SPORT"
    export SPORT=archery
    echo "$SPORT"
)

printf 'SPORT is "%s"\n' "$SPORT"
```

The output will remain the same.

It is impossible for one environment to affect another *with one exception*: A new environment inherits environment variables from the parent environment. A subshell (as in the last example) also inherits unexported shell variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write that out for me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Beware of the variables with _universal_ scope in `fish` (synchronised between `fish` invocations with persistence on the filesystem) which can also be exported.

Answer (score 3):

That's not what environment variables *means.*  An "environment" is specific to a process.  It may (or may not) be inherited by other processes forked from that process, depending on various things.  Modifying the environment of a running process will never affect other running processes.*

Read up on what environment variables mean under the hood in [the POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08).  (And understand this document is aimed at *implementors*, not at users.)

<sub>*or at least, contriving an exception to this would require some very good low-level coding skills.  I don't know if it's possible in C; perhaps with shared memory.  But it wouldn't happen without being explicitly designed that way.</sub>